# Cocoa: How to have a context menu when you right-click on a cell of NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, contextmenu, nstableview

I have a TableView with custom cells. I want a contextual menu to appear when the user right clicks (or any other Apple variants of right-click) on one of the cells (and know which cell they clicked on).

I tried to subclass NSTableView and overwrite this method:

```
- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
```

But it is never being called.

On the other hand,

```
- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
```

Gets called. But I'm not sure it's the one we want.

More details:

```
//
//  PTTableView.m
// 
//
//  Created by Nathan Hazout on 5/31/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PTTableView.h"


@implementation PTTableView

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent { 
    NSLog(@"entered rightMouseDown");
}

- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"entered menuForEvent");
    return [super menuForEvent:theEvent];
}

- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint{
    NSLog(@"entered hitTest");
    return [super hitTest:aPoint];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

rightMouseDown gets called. hiTest gets called many times. But menuForEvent doesn't.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There's no need to muck about with event handling, all you have to do to assign a contextual menu is set the table view's `menu` outlet to point to the `NSMenu` object that you want to use for the contextual menu.

You can do this in Interface Builder by dropping an `NSMenu` object into your nib file and control-dragging from the table view to the menu to set the outlet.

Alternatively, you can use the `-setMenu:` method of `NSTableView` (inherited from `NSResponder`) to assign the menu programmatically.

Comment: Should I do it on the TableView or the Cell?

Comment: You assign the contextual menu to the view.

Comment: Hi Rob, could you please point out what should I do to open the same context menu on left-clicking (instead of right).

Comment: @shy There should only be one contextual menu for any UI item.  Control-click, left-click (mouse) and two-finger click (pad) are the common accessors for this menu.  The standard tap/click is for interacting with the table/cells.  (i.e. i believe this is already doing what you want)

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this, you get the associated row with `tableView.clickedRow`

Comment: Well, it's not really contextual if its the same item for every item then, is it? (using table views `menu`)

Comment: @ErikAigner that's what the menu validation delegate methods are for.

Comment: @RobKeniger yes and no. Then you have tons of disabled fields. But I guess it's better to have disabled fields compared to a different menu for each item.

Comment: @ErikAigner it's possible to use the `NSMenu` delegate methods (specifically `menu(NSMenu, update: NSMenuItem, at: Int, shouldCancel: Bool)`) to hide menu items that aren't relevant before the menu displays.

Comment: Nota: the -validateMenuItem: delegate method is now in NSMenuItemValidation delegate protocol.

Answer (score 20):

A Swift 4 version of Rob's answer:

Add the menu:

```
let menu = NSMenu()
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Edit", action: #selector(tableViewEditItemClicked(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(tableViewDeleteItemClicked(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
tableView.menu = menu
```

The functions:

```
@objc private func tableViewEditItemClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard tableView.clickedRow >= 0 else { return }

    let item = items[tableView.clickedRow]

    showDetailsViewController(with: item)
}

@objc private func tableViewDeleteItemClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard tableView.clickedRow >= 0 else { return }

    items.remove(at: tableView.clickedRow)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This solution creates a blue border around the cell

Comment: @Sentry.co I'm not sure why this solution would do that as it has no styling attributes.

Comment: what is showDetailsViewController method?

Comment: @iHTCboy Just a method that calls DetailsVC with the selected item